# Class FlurryPLCrashReportSystemInfo is implemented in app and Cocoapods

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, flurry

```
source 'git@github.com:Internal/PrivatePodspecs.git'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '13.0'

project 'Project.xcodeproj'

def shared
    pod 'MBProgressHUD', '1.1.0', :inhibit_warnings => true
    pod 'Crashlytics', '3.14.0', :inhibit_warnings => true
    pod 'TTTAttributedLabel', '2.0.0', :inhibit_warnings => true
    pod 'Flurry-iOS-SDK/FlurrySDK'
    pod 'PhoneNumberKit', '2.6.0', :inhibit_warnings => true
    pod 'Firebase/Analytics', '6.2.0', :inhibit_warnings => true
    pod 'CardScan', '1.0.5040', :inhibit_warnings => true

    # Internal Dependencies
    pod 'InternalLibA'
    pod 'InternalLibB'
    pod 'InternalLibC'
    pod 'InternalLibD'
    pod 'InternalLibE'
    pod 'InternalLibF'

target 'Project' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  
  pre_install do |installer|
  Pod::Installer::Xcode::TargetValidator.send(:define_method, :verify_no_static_framework_transitive_dependencies) {}
  end

  # Pods for Project
  shared

deployment_target = '13.0'

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
     config.build_settings['ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH'] = 'YES'
     config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = deployment_target
    end
  end
end
```

Above is the podfile I'm currently using to get my app to compile with Xcode 14.  The compiler is throwing multiple errors complaining of multiple Flurry classes being implemented in both an internal library and the app itself.  This is enough to cause Flurry to stop communicating with the back end.

In testing, I've found that if I change each of the libraries it's complaining of being implemented in both to a static library then the errors of class is implemented in both go away. However, it causes a crash because one of the libraries refuses to work when linked statically.

What else can I try to get these errors to go away? I'm at a loss. I've looked through every SO and github link that comes up but I'm still banging my head against the wall.

It complains of more classes than just FlurryPLCrashReportSystemInfo

some of the others include

FlurryStreamCrashReporter

FlurryPaymentTransactionSource

FlurryStreamAppTransparencyStatus

FlurryConfigInfoDataProvider

FlurryStreamLaunchOptions

FlurryDataProvider

FlurryActorDeferredQueue

FlurryStreamSessionPropertiesParamsDropRule

FlurryLocationDataProvider

FlurryWatch

etc

Answer (score 0):

You can use the lite version of Flurry which does not include the PLCrashReporter.

pod 'Flurry-iOS-SDK/FlurrySDK', '12.1.1-lite'

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply.  I have edited the original question, there are more classes than just FlurryPLCrashReportSystemInfo throwing errors about being implemented in both.  I did try the lite version, and I do no longer see a specific error about FlurryPLCrashReportSystemInfo i still do get errors from other classes.  I appreciate any help.